# Opening FLV AAC stream in VLC

Tags: audio, vlc-media-player, streaming, aac

When I run vlc from the command line and pass it the url of a stream I want to listen to, it works:

```
$ vlc http://14143.live.streamtheworld.com/CJMOFMAAC
```

But when I try to open this url from within VLC via the GUI to play a network stream, it fails and gives me an error, `VLC is unable to open the MRL 'http://14143.live.streamtheworld.com/CJMOFMAAC'.`

Where in the GUI can I give it the same string that I'm passing it via the command line?

Comment: Selecting menu item "Media -> Open Network Stream" and pasting the http url works for me!  How did you try to open this URL/stream in the GUI?

Comment: That's the same method I used, though I'm just realizing that I might be getting blocked by my office's firewall. The thing is, capturing this stream is actually for a work project!

Comment: The usual blocked-by-proxy problem.  Thanks for posting an answer showing how to set the proxy in VLC.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that I needed to enter my proxy settings into VLC. Under `Tools -> Preferences -> Input / Codecs -> Network -> HTTP proxy URL` I put in `my.proxy.domain:port`

This did the trick.